# "Chapter" vs. "Section" or "Topic"

Tags: word-usage

With the popularity of online help (available on the Internet), book-based terminology, such as "chapter" and "book", don't make much sense. For example, as far as the reader is concerned, there are no "chapters" in online help. A chapter is simply a collection of topics or sections. This especially applies to topic-based writing.

I would rather refer to book-based terminology in a more general way. Is it more common to refer to "section" instead of "chapter"?

Comment: Some reference books are explicitly divided into "chapters", but usually only if the information contained therein can usefully be seen as progressing from simple to complex things (presented as a temporal sequence / narrative to be followed by a learner). But it's not a particularly useful concept for html-based online help text, which will often have links to "outline" (chapter heading?) as well as "more detail" and "related" links that mean to an extent the reader can impose whatever structure suits his current requirement, regardless of what "groupings" the author had in mind.

Comment: "resource" is another word that comes to mind. "Resources in our online knowledge base" .  Category is a classification of something but doesn't cast that much light on that "something's" purpose .. but if you were to have collections of resources indexed by related matter it could work.  "Section" might be better though because it could better refer to an interconnected and perhaps partially sequential collection of resources. ... i.e.  each "section" might have a "overview" a "getting started, it's own FAQ and as well as more specialized resources..which might themselves have "advanced"

Comment: What exactly are you trying to name? Is it one page which deals with different topic? Or one page with multiple topics? Or multiple pages with different topics? Without an idea of the type of website, it's hard to answer your question. Consider a Wikipedia page on some topic, you might say that's structured into sections and subsections. Wikipedia as a whole consists of many topics (each with their own page). On this site, I'd refer to the different pages as questions. As you see, it depends on the site and what exactly on the site you want to refer to.

Comment: One page can contain multiple topics. Here's an example of the first page of what is called a chapter in the print/PDF book: https://www.jmp.com/support/help/14/the-big-picture.shtml.  I don't want to call it a chapter in the help because chapter is a book-based term. So that leaves me wondering which is more appropriate -- "section" or "topic".

Comment: Your Question seems to be seeking a solution to no-one's problem. “Chapter" is a content-based term there's no need to change. “Section” and “topic” aren’t alternatives.

Broadly, “section” refers to a chunk of text; “topic” to a subject.

There are often "chapters" in on-line anything; they just happen either to ignore, or to be *more* clearly defined by pagination.

You might try to make it difficult to accept a terminology covering both modern and traditional formats for text but why bother, please? Why not just use appropriate terms for each?